# Macro to get ranges for each unique value in column

Tags: excel, vba, range, union

I have the following code that displays unique values in column B and the row numbers where each value appears. It works, but my final goal
is to print the ranges where each unique value appears.

```
Sub GetRanges()

Set aw = Application.WorksheetFunction
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
arr = Application.Transpose(Range("B1:B" & LastRow).Value)

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            d(arr(i)) = d(arr(i)) & "," & i
    Next i

For Each Key In d.Keys
    Debug.Print Key, Mid(d(Key), 2)
Next Key

End Sub
```

The input data from A1:B19 is:

```
    A           B
1   BLOCK ABC    
2   Code        Number
3   RRU         91
4   OCJS        103
5   IE          43
6   UHDI        109
7   IJCD        109
8   EIE         109
9   BLOCK DEF    
10  Code        Number
11  UUTY        109
12  EER         109
13  BLOCK GHI    
14  Code        Number
15  RUO         223
16  YUH         223
17  JKKPW       223
18  OOOI        223
19  JSDDF       82
```

The current output that shows rows where each unique value in Column B appears is:

```
Value     |  Rows 
--------------------------
          |  1,9,13
Number    |  2,10,14
91        |  3
103       |  4
43        |  5
109       |  6,7,8,11,12
223       |  15,16,17,18
82        |  19
```

I would like to get the ranges for each unique value like this:

```
Value    |    Range 
--------------------------
         |    1,9,13
Number   |    2,10,14
91       |    3
103      |    4
43       |    5
109      |    6-8,11-12
223      |    15-18
82       |    19
         |
```

This means that

- For `empty` value there are 3 ranges, Range("A1:B1"), Range("A9:B9") and Range("A13:B13")
- For `109` there are 2 ranges, Range("A6:B8") and Range("A11:B12")

My final goal is join in a single Range using `Union()` to colorize with different colors the rows related with each unique value but I don't want to use Autofilter method since is slow.

Maybe someone could help with this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change the row numbers to ranges the perform a little text processing, Union can group your row numbers together.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetRanges()

    Dim str As String, d As Object, lr As Long, arr As Variant, i As Long, key As Variant

    lr = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    arr = Application.Transpose(Range("B1:B" & lr).Value)

    Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
        'collect items as range references
        d(arr(i)) = d(arr(i)) & ",Z" & i
    Next i


    'process row numbers as range
    For Each key In d.Keys
        'collect key's item
        str = Mid(d(key), 2)
        'union the range address back to str
        str = Union(Range(str), Range(str)).Address(0, 0)
        'remove column and swap colons for hyphens
        str = Replace(Replace(str, "Z", vbNullString), ":", "-")
        'replace key's item with processed str
        d(key) = str
    Next key

    For Each key In d.Keys
        Debug.Print key, d(key)
    Next key

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much. It works. Nice trick about `Union` and  `Address(0,0)`  I have the issue to Union() the separated rows or ranges in a single joined range. I'll see.